# Missing '}' in Minecraft Bedrock 'can_destroy' command?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

No matter what I do it keeps saying I'm missing a closing bracket, "}". My command is:

```
/give @p stone_shovel 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy" : {"blocks" : ["grass"]}}
```